# Writing a Java class inside my Scala application

Tags: scala

I wanted to know if I can write a Java class inside my scala application? My scala is complied with sbt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using the standard sbt settings, you can put .java files into src/main/java and/or src/test/java and they will be compiled by sbt along with your .scala files.

Comment: you meant src/main/java ?

Comment: @mahdi62 Yes, I did. Sorry about that.